# Is there any specific reason why Gnome Terminal Emulator uses Shift+Ctl+V and not the typical Ctrl+V?

Tags: gnome-terminal, keyboard-layout, shortcuts

Typically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> are considered the standard keyboard shortcuts for cutting and pasting.

In Ubuntu 15.04 Gnome Terminal Emulator the shortcuts use an additional <kbd>Shift</kbd> key which turns the everyday process of cutting and pasting in to some kind of Vulcun death grip (reminding me of the days of rebooting my SGI workstation).

Is this a deliberate reason for this additional key, something I'm not considering, or can I happily change it without any consequences?

[image: Gnome Terminal Emulator Shortcuts Window Screengrab]

Comment: The easiest way, of course, is to just select the text (which copies it automatically) and then middle-click to paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

the typical shortcut for copy  and paste on the terminal (not only on gnome and not even only on gnu/linux is ctr + shift + v.

Ctrl + c is Interrupt/Kill whatever you are running (SIGINT). It would not be prudent to change that.
These shortcuts are older than Ctrl + c, ctrl + v.

A more elaborate and better answer is here:
https://superuser.com/questions/421463/why-does-ctrl-v-not-paste-in-bash-linux-shell

Comment: Ah, yes I'd completed forgotten about killing a process. Doh!